# Datagridview how to fill data from another datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

in my invoicing software I have the "master" datagridview which I integrated with a lookup feature: once user presses F3 while on the Code field, it shows a modal form with another datagridview that shows a list of products to choose from.
[image]
[image]

Where i'm stuck is where user clicks Ok on the selected products, because I don't know well how to fill the Datagridview correctly in order to have all on the same row. Here's my code:

```
Private Function RicercaxCodiceArticolo(ByVal codiceart As String)

    Dim strsql As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim source As New BindingSource
    Dim count As Integer

    connection.Open()
    strsql = "SELECT CODICEARTICOLO AS 'Codice', DESCRIZIONEARTICOLO AS 'Descrizione', UNITAMISURA AS 'Um', CODICEIVA AS 'Iva' " _
            & ",COSTOBASE AS 'Costo', PREZZOBASE AS 'Prezzo', COSTOULTIMO AS 'Costo Ult.', BARCODE AS 'Barcode', NOTEARTICOLO AS 'Note' " _
            & ",CATEGORIAARTICOLO AS 'Categ.Art.', GIACENZA AS 'Giacenza', FORNITOREPREF AS 'Fornit. Pref.' FROM Articoli " _
            & " WHERE CODICEARTICOLO = '" & codiceart & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = strsql
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = connection
    'TODO: Completare
    source.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(source.Current!Codice)
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(source.Current!Descrizione)
    connection.Close()

End Function
```

Of course the second line of the Add method is wrong, but how do I fill all the data on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well … I will assume a couple of things that you are neglecting to tell us.

1. We must assume that the first grid does NOT use a `DataSource` and the columns are added in the designer or in some code you are not showing. This assumption is based on the code that adds the rows directly to the grid since you can not add rows directly to the grid when it is data bound.
2. Also, I will assume that the line of code …

   `source.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader`

   … is returning a `DataTable` from the SQL command `cmd`.

If both my assumptions are correct, then in my small tests, the line of code…

```
source.Current
```

Will return a `DataRowView` object of the “selected” row in `source` and you simply need to cast it to a `DataRowView` to get the values you want to add to the single row in the grid. Something like…

```
Dim drv As DataRowView
drv = CType(source.Current, DataRowView)
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(drv("Codice"), drv("Descrizione"))
```

Lastly, it may be a better approach to use a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` for the first grid's `BindingSource` and simply "Import" the row into the `DataTable`. Pick your own poison.

Comment: The first grid does not use data sources at all. It is an unbound grid, which receives data only from the second grid, once user presses designated key for search, so i'm not denying any code, it is simply that I tought it was useless to show anything else. Anyway, thanks for the help.